# Visual 2015 C++ compiler: Call of static member with object does not lead to compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I noticed that I do not get a compiler error for the following code.
Instead the program hangs. Why is that so?

```
class GLvector
{
public:
  static GLvector CrossProduct(const GLvector &V1, const GLvector &V2);

// ..

GLvector v;
v.CrossProduct(foo, bar);
```

Comment: You may call a static function using member access operator applied to a class object.

Comment: hanging might be because of some _other_  issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to call a `static` function through an object of your class but you **CAN** call it through object.

Calling the `static` function through an object doesn't causes any compiler errors and it also doesn't hangs your program. Program hanging in your case might be because of some other issue.